# Why doesn't my script file work in index.ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I load the page, the

## What is up

shows up, but the "Hello World" from the script.js doesn't.
Any help?

The directory looks like this

```
project
 |
 +-- node modules
 |    
 +-- javascript
 |  |  
 |  +-- script.js
 |    
 +-- views
 |  |  
 |  |  +-- index.ejs
 |    
 +-- server.js
 |
 +-- package.json
```

**index.ejs file**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Index</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Index">

</head>

<body>
  
  <h1>What is up?</h1>

  <div id = "container">
    
  </div>

</body>

<script src = "javascript/script.js">
    
// var container = document.getElementById("container");
// var content = document.createTextNode("Hello, World!");
// container.appendChild(content);

</script>
</html>
```

The commented out code in the script is exactly whats included in the script.js file. If I uncomment it, and have the code running in the ejs file, it works. Just not if in the external script.js

**server.js file**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('view-engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('project/javascript'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Try to place the script tag inside the body (before the body's closing tag)

Comment: Why is that important?

Comment: Because you can be more confident that all HTML elements are loaded at that point. Since your are using the <div id="container">. Even better would be to listen for DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the `src`-attribute to an absolute path, this should work fine:

```
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

Note that I've removed the `/javascript` subfolder from the url since this is not correct. Also you should pass the subfolder to `express.static`, i.e.:

```
app.use(express.static('javascript'));
```